# Swift get request returning unauthorised

Tags: swift

I'm using a get request to request data from predicthq, for some reason I keep receiving a response of  `{"error": "unauthorized"}` as the JSON response. I've changed the API a few times now with no luck. I have tried it within Postman and the data is getting returned...

This is the python example they provide:

```
response = requests.get(
url="https://api.predicthq.com/v1/events",
headers={
  "Authorization": "Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN",
  "Accept": "application/json"
}
)
```

This is the request I'm using, the API key is 100% correct as I've used it to make a request on their website:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://api.predicthq.com/v1/events")
    guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }
    // Create URL Request
    var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
    // Headers
    request.addValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    // Specify HTTP Method to use
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    // Send HTTP Request
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        // Check if Error took place
        if let error = error {
            print("Error took place \(error)")
            return
        }

        // Read HTTP Response Status code
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print("Response HTTP Status code: \(response.statusCode)")
        }

        // Convert HTTP Response Data to a simple String
        if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Response data string:\n \(dataString)")
        }

    }
    task.resume()
```

Edit: I have also tried using AlamoFire with the same result.

```
let path = "https://api.predicthq.com/v1/events"
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"]


    AF.request(path, method: .get, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { (response) in
        if let data = response.data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Response data string:\n \(dataString)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any chance `token` variable be an optional (`String?`) or an implicitly unwrapped optional (`String!`)?

Comment: I have tried unwrapping with the same result @gcharita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the issue has been identified. `"https://api.predicthq.com/v1/events"` needs a `/` at the end and it works fine.